# Apache rewrite rule for html5 pushstate with proxy and exclusions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, pushstate

I am using `apache` as `http` server, `tomcat8` as application server (`rest`) and `express` as `angular2` static server.

Following is my virtual host element

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ... other things - name path and logs ...


    ProxyPass /rest/ http://localhost:8080/rest/
    ProxyPassReverse /rest/ http://localhost:8080/rest/

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Basically what I am doing is, whenever someone hits `http://localhost` he should see static web app which is hosted on `http://localhost:3000` and when someone (web application) make request for `http://localhost/rest`, request should reach to `tomcat8` on `8080` for rest call.

This is working properly.

**Now what I want**

I am using `express` static server which serves `angular2` application. This application uses `html5` `pushState` as router. Whenever user refreshes the page, it shows not found error.

I want redirection rule which redirect as following

`http://localhost/somepath` => `http://localhost?redirect=/somepath`

`http://localhost/rest` => (do not rewrite but proceed to proxy) `http://localhost:8080/rest`

I am not getting how to use rewrite rule here.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/rest/)
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "!(.*(?:^|&))_redirect=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "http://localhost?_redirect=$1" [L,R,NE,QSA]
```

Above is my code for same, but it is not working. Can anyone suggest me proper condition and rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I end up doing

```
    RewriteEngine  on
    // exception for everything which is on the webapp but has physical path
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/rest/)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/bootstrap-template/)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/lib/)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/app/)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/assets/)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/browser-sync/)    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/node_modules/)    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/styles.css)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/Helvetica.otf)$
    // exceptions end

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/)(.+)$
    RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "!(.*(?:^|&))_redirect=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$"
    RewriteRule "^/(.*)"        "http://localhost?_redirect=$1" [L,R,NE,QSA]

    ProxyPass /pixie/ http://localhost:8080/pixie/
    ProxyPassReverse /pixie/ http://localhost:8080/pixie/

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```