# Angular 2 Not Found (404) errors after uploading to web host

Tags: angular

Running my app on apache (web hosting) works like a charm, with one problem:

The router routes return 404 Not Found error. I can use my app as excepted, but when I'll try to refresh the page when I'm at **myAppUrl/myApp/componentName**.

Although, when I navigate in my app, the routers working, as soon as I don't refresh the page - No 404 error is shown.

What's wrong? Any .htaccess configuration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167308/apache-rewrite-rule-for-html5-pushstate-with-proxy-and-exclusions

Comment: I tried to follow and understand what he was doing there, unsuccesfully, and this way is ugly and bootless

Comment: I'm sure there are othet anseers out there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894769/understanding-what-it-takes-to-remove-the-hash-from-angular-routes

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, but the answer there is more likely talking about why it happens, and I already know it's somethign about the apache configuration - but no idea how to .htaccess file has to be.